# An alternative to StreamBuilder/NotificationListener

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any `Widget` in Flutter that can rebuild, whenever it receives an notification from an **instantiated** ChangeNotifier?

Comment: There is some other ways such as RXdart, provider, scoped model and even bloc can be alternative but I think you need to explain more, why you need an alternative, for what cause?

Comment: As far as I know, they directly accept Class as a type parameter ... I wanted to know if there is any Widget in Flutter that can **rebuild** on **notification** from an instantiated Notifier. Being able to rebuild on a simple notification is the requirement.

Comment: A concrete sample would be more clear but as I understand you want to work instantiate objects in flutter but as I know, Flutter has no type of instance of classes so the problem is not only stream builder or any builder,  but there is some libraries which help that issue such as https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable, I didn't use such as objects so far so I can't help a lot, sorry. But like I said a concrete example about what are you trying to do would be more clear to understand, and getting help.